# A generic error occurred in GDI+ exception when saving bitmap

Tags: c#, .net, bitmap, gdi+

I'm trying to save a file in my project bin folder. For some reason when I give it a string as a path such as

```
string filePath = @"C:\Users\Craig\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\CreateTextExample\CreateTextExample\bin\ErrorLog";
Thread.Sleep(100);
bitmap.Save(filePath+@"\ErrorImage.Bmp", ImageFormat.Bmp);
```

it saves the file fine. However when I try and save it like

```
string filePath = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\ErrorLog";
Thread.Sleep(100);
bitmap.Save(filePath+@"\ErrorImage.Bmp", ImageFormat.Bmp);
```

I get a runtime error saying `A generic error occurred in GDI+`

Not sure why this is happening. Initially I thought it may have been the folder permissions however this doesn't seem to be the case as it works using the first method.[image]

Any ideas why this is happening?

My code is as follows

```
string currentContent = String.Empty;

bitmap = new Bitmap(System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);
Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap as Image);
graphics.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, bitmap.Size);

string filePath = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\ErrorLog";
Thread.Sleep(100);
bitmap.Save(filePath+@"\ErrorImage.Bmp", ImageFormat.Bmp);
```

Comment: Why are you sleeping the thread?  Also, use [`System.IO.Path.Combine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine(v=vs.110).aspx) for concatenating paths, much cleaner.

Comment: The exception stack might be useful

Comment: "it works using the first method". When you have eliminated the impossible, whatever remains, however improbable, must be the truth. Does `System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` return what you think it returns? Is `filePath` `C:\Users\Craig\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\CreateTextExample\CreateTextExample\bin\ErrorLog` in the second approach too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using the Save method of the `Bitmap` you should ensure that the directory exist. In the first case your directory is this:

**This directory should exist in your system**

`C:\Users\Craig\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\CreateTextExample\CreateTextExample\bin\ErrorLog`

But in the second case (when using `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory` method) your directory should be something like this (it may have a extera `Debug` or `Release` folder before the `ErrorLog`)

**These directories should not exist in your system (depending you are in Debug or Release Mode)**

`C:\Users\Craig\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\CreateTextExample\CreateTextExample\bin\Debug\ErrorLog`

`C:\Users\Craig\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\CreateTextExample\CreateTextExample\bin\Release\ErrorLog`

So `bitmap.Save` throws error because the directory does not exists in your system.

Comment: Yes I've just realised that it has Debug in the path. So stupid of me. Thanks for pointing this out

Comment: @CraigGallagher whenever you got a right answer for your question in StackOverflow, don't forget to mark it as answer, so others having the same problem would be easier guided.

Comment: Will do now :) Thanks